# Block "play" headset button in an Android app

Tags: android, audio

I am writing an Android app that reads external hardware through the microphone input. My problem is that sometimes the phone thinks that the signals that are coming through the mic are "play" button presses and starts playing music. (the play button shorts microphone to ground, and some of the signals I'm reading are close enough to that)

I have seen apps that block the play button from a headset. I wonder how I can add this functionality to my own app.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: Set up a broadcast receiver for the ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON intent and handle it so it doesn't get passed on the music app.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should AC couple your input signal with a series capacitor?  This will give a limit on the low frequency response, but you probably shouldn't depend on that anyway.